# 'Json parse error:Unexpected token:o ' error when using JSON.parse with asyncStorage

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

So i'm getting an error 'JSON Parse error:Unexpected token:o' while trying to save a 'tarefa' with asyncStorage with react and expo .There is the code :

```
  if (tarefa!==null){
    AsyncStorage.setItem('@task:key',JSON.stringify(tarefa))

  }else{
    alert('error')
  }

  const a = JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem('@task:key')  );
  if (a!== null) {
    // We have data!!
    console.log(a);
}else{
  alert('didnt work')
}
```

```
<TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Clean the house..."
        onSubmitEditing={(value) => {
            setTarefa(value.nativeEvent.text); 
            alert(tarefa)
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.textcaixa}></Text>
      </TextInput>
```

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={saveTarefa}>
        <Text style={styles.TextSave}>Save tasks</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

I'm expecting  the code to save the 'tarefa' in the asyncstorage